# Data for web security/database security issues

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, security

I'm still thinking of a topic for my bachelor's thesis. I'm thinking of something like machine learning application on web security/database security. Problem is, in machine learning I need to have data. So I thought I'll base my topic on what kind of data I would get. Example, I found data on web intrusion then I'll have a topic somewhere on the line of web intrusion detection.

Answer (score 3):

[CVE](https://cve.mitre.org/) is a freely usable database of security issues, many of them related to web/database.

The CVE database can be downloaded at https://cve.mitre.org/data/downloads/index.html as XML, CSV, and other formats.

A typical entry includes:

- Name
- Description
- Status
- Phase
- References

Answer (score 1):

[NVD](https://nvd.nist.gov/cpe.cfm) is a freely usable dictionary which consist of vulnerabilities.

Also, this dictionary belongs to [NIST](http://www.nist.gov). Therefore this dictionary always up to date.